# How to clear cache programmatically in Drupal 8?

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

I am working on a Drupal 8 site. This site was working. I recently moved to another machine.

It is showing errors like:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to 

Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::__construct() must be of

 the type array, boolean given, called in [DRUPAL-

PATH]/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php on line 883 and defined in 

[DRUPAL-PATH]/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php

 on line 119 #0 [DRUPAL-PATH]/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(550): 

_drupal_error_handler_real(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', 

'/Applications/M...', 119, Array)
```

I need to clear cache programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By SQL**

```
TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE `cache_config`;
TRUNCATE `cache_container`;
TRUNCATE `cache_data`;
TRUNCATE `cache_default`;
TRUNCATE `cache_discovery`;
TRUNCATE `cache_dynamic_page_cache`;
TRUNCATE `cache_entity`;
TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE `cache_render`;
TRUNCATE `cache_rest`;
TRUNCATE `cachetags`;
TRUNCATE `cache_toolbar`;
```

**By Drush**

```
drush cr all
```

Comment: As mentionned by sreekanth kuriyala, theres a function for it : `drupal_flush_all_caches()`

Answer (score 32):

Try below.

```
cache_clear_all() // For Drupal-7

drupal_flush_all_caches() // For Drupal-8
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer since the OP said "programmatically".

Answer (score 26):

If you want to clear specific cache like **render cache** then you can run the following  code:

```
\Drupal::service('cache.render')->invalidateAll()
```

If you want to clear all the cache then try:

```
drupal_flush_all_caches()
```

The following services implement the `CacheBackendInterface` and has `invalidateAll()` method which marks all the cache items as invalid:

```
cache.bootstrap
cache.config
cache.data
cache.default
cache.discovery
cache.entity
cache.menu
cache.render
cache.static
```

Comment: If you want to be even more granular, then figure out the cache ID and `\Drupal::service('cache.render')->invalidate($cid)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Programmatically using PHP**
just use this method where you want to clear the cache:

```
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

there are also other methods to clear caches using:

**By Admin UI**

Navigate to /admin/config/development/performance and ​click the button "Clear all caches".

**By Drush**

```
drush cache-rebuild
//or you can use
drush cr
```

**By update.php**
Run update.php (/update.php) is another way of clearing the cache.

**By SQL**
Delete all data inside  tables that start with "cache_" like this:

```
TRUNCATE cache_config;
TRUNCATE cache_container;
TRUNCATE cache_data;
TRUNCATE cache_default;
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;
TRUNCATE cache_dynamic_page_cache;
TRUNCATE cache_entity;
TRUNCATE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE cache_render;
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;
```

**Other Methods:**

```
$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;

\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

cache_clear_all() // For Drupal-7

drupal_flush_all_caches() // For Drupal-8
```

If you want to clear specific cache like render cache then you can run the following code:

```
\Drupal::service('cache.render')->invalidateAll();
```

If you want to clear a specific cache like route-cache then you can run the following code:

```
\Drupal::service("router.builder")->rebuild();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for a way to clear the cache of all views:

```
views_invalidate_cache();
```

is your friend!